# Vue $emit passing argument to a function that already have arguments

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this in my component:

```
template: <input @blur="$emit('customEvent', arg1)" v-model="arg1">
```

And this in my html template:

```
<component @customEvent="method1(arg2)"></component>
```

I need to provide a parameter (`arg2`) to the `method1()` function, but also I need to get the `arg1` from `$emit()`.

I tried this (into the Vue instance):

```
method1(arg2, arg1) {
      console.log("This is the arg2: " + arg2);
      console.log("This is the arg1: " + arg1);
    }
```

Of course, I tried to reverse them, not working, the `arg1`is not getting passed, but replaced.

I know it must have a namespace (perhaps something like `arg1=arg1`), but I haven't found anything like this.

Comment: whether this is parent and child component communication.

Comment: I want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It can work by passing `$event` into the methods.

`$event` will be the payload you pass in the emit function. When you do `$emit('customEvent', arg1)`, `arg1` will be passed as `$event` to @customEvent.

```
<component @customEvent="method1($event, arg2)"></component>
```

and in methods:

```
method1(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log("This is the arg2: " + arg2);
  console.log("This is the arg1: " + arg1);
}
```

proof of concept: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/e8a5k3ph/1/

---

alternative solution:

```
<component @customEvent="(eventPayload) => method1(eventPayload, arg2)"></component>
```

Comment: Works amazing, and i've been lookin for this solution for a long time.. but to be honest this is really looks like a hack :/

Comment: @Dany
an alternative that feels less like a hack is to pass a function to the event handler. 
`@customEvent="(eventPayload) => method1(eventPayload, arg2)"`