# Re-emit event with multiple parameters

Tags: vue.js, events

I am using a component that `$emit`s an event with multiple values.  Oftentimes, I just want to re-emit that same event up to higher parent component.  When I try `@input="$emit('input', $event)"`, it only re-emits the first parameter.

How can I emit both?

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Use a handler method:

```vue
<template>
  <component @input="emitInput" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    emitInput(param1, param2) {
      this.$emit('input', param1, param2);
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Option 2: Use an inline function:

```vue
<template>
  <component @input="(param1, param2) => $emit('input', param1, param2)" />
</template>
```

If using a render function, it will look like this:

```vue
render(createElement) {
  return createElement(MyComponent, {
    on: {
      input: (param1, param2) => this.$emit('input', param1, param2),
    },
});
```

Note: This method was inspired by [Jacob Goh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5599288/jacob-goh) from his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49729845/4468423) and subsequent [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729384/vue-emit-passing-argument-to-a-function-that-already-have-arguments#comment114228623_49729845) to a similar question that I felt deserved its own question and answer.

Comment: You can also make this agnostic to the number of arguments by using spreads:

`<component @input="(...args) => $emit('input', ...args)" />`